# Google Sheets: Instead of using a cell reference (such as A1) can I use a command that returns a cell reference as a parameter?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to use `SUMIFS` on a specified area, but this area changes depending on the variable it uses to search it. Therefore I'm using `ADDRESS` to return the `R1C1` of the start and end cells. However, `SUMIFS` and other commands won't accept anything other than `R1C1`, which I cannot provide statically. How do I get this to work?

Basically - `ADDRESS` returns an address like `E9`. However,
I want to use a command like `SUM(ADDRESS(~~~):ADDRESS(~~~))` but that doesn't work, instead I have to use `SUM(E9:E45)` instead. Is there a way to make the first one work?

Comment: This might help `SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(~~~) & ":" & ADDRESS(~~~)))`. But for sure there are better approaches to be suggested - an example sheet is needed for that. Could you provide one?

Answer (score 2):

Use [INDIRECT](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093377?hl=en)

Example

```
=SUM(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1)&":"&ADDRESS(3,1)))
```